# Do the summation properties of limits still hold if $x$ approaches infinity?

Tags: limits

If we have the limit of two functions as $x$ approaches infinity equaling 0, then does this imply if we add these two functions and take the limit, it will still be 0? I'm 99 percent sure they do but most of the books I have regarding properties of limits speak of the limit as $x$ approaches some point $c$ (which is a limit point)

Comment: Yes, because addition is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The sum of the limits is the limit of the sums (if they both converge).

It is a sequences and series proof of convergence of two sequences.

Comment: Well I am just considering real valued functions from the real numbers to the real numbers such that both functions have a limit of 0 as $x$ approaches infinity.

Comment: Use the definition of convergence.

Comment: Oh I am not proving anything, I was just checking if my intuition was right.

Comment: As long as f, g both converge to 0, f+g converges to 0.

Comment: Yup that is all I wanted to clarify. I was right in assuming so. I just wanted to be sure with a little bit of input from others, not that this is a complicated problem/idea.